# How to change a property of all listview items in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the `BorderThickness` property of all items in a ListView(*WPF*). The problem is that my listview's items are binding to properties of a List, where `Song` is a class. Here is how I bind them:

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewPlaylist" Margin="-4,-3,0,3" SelectionChanged="ListviewPlaylist_SelectionChanged" AllowDrop="True" Drop="ListviewPlaylist_Drop" DragEnter="ListviewPlaylist_DragEnter" PreviewMouseDown="ListviewPlaylist_PreviewMouseDown" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler" MouseMove="ListviewPlaylist_MouseMove">
         <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Album" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Track no" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TrackNo}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Duration" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration}" />
                 </GridView>
           </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If I now try to loop through `listviewPlaylist.Items`, I can't cast `itemObj` as a `ListViewItem`:

```
foreach (var itemObj in listviewPlaylist.Items)
            {
                var lvItem = (ListViewItem)itemObj; 
                lvItem.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            }
```

I then get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'MayPlayer.Song' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem'.'

Is there a way to access the items from the `ListView` instead of the class?
I haven't found any solutions on the internet for this, I've also tried:

```
var lvItem = itemObj as ListViewItem;
```

I'm not sure or there are more things that I have to add to this question, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Thanks to ASh, I used `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
Style style = new Style();
style.TargetType = typeof(ListViewItem);
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(1)));
listviewPlaylist.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` generates `ListViewItem` for data items in `ItemsSource`, but those `ListViewItems` are not directly accessibly (*and they are not supposed to  really. When virtualization is enabled, one ListViewItem can be reused for multiple data items, when scrolling the ListView*). Use `ItemContainerStyle` to change their properties:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
       <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```